# Private variables with requirejs and closure

Tags: javascript, requirejs, closures

I am trying to make a class with private variables in requirejs. ( means I don't want anyone to access this variable and only private method can be used.)

#### numbox.js

```
define(function(){
  var counter=0;
  function Numbox(){
  }
  Numbox.prototype = {
    add_and_show:function(){
      counter++; alert(counter);
    }
  }
  return Numbox;
}
```

This is not correct if I create any new instance of Numbox and call the method, all instances will share the same counter as follows.

```
require(['numbox.js'], function(Numbox){
  var box1 = new Numbox();
  var box2 = new Numbox();
  box1.add_and_show(); // alert(1);
  box2.add_and_show(); // alert(2); instead of "1"
}
```

And even though I put counter under constructer function as follows,  It can work but it does not realize my goal as I want it to be private. (I can still access "counter" by box1.counter or box2.counter)

#### numbox.js

```
define(function(){
  function Numbox(){
    this.counter =0;
  }
  Numbox.prototype = {
    add_and_show:function(){
      this.counter++; alert(this.counter);
    }
  }
  return Numbox;
}
```

Please suggest the correct way to do this. Thx!

Comment: You're second version is fine, there's no such thing as private and public in JavaScript. I'd say don't worry about it. If you really want to do it you'd have to keep track of instances and counters somehow.

Answer (score 3):

You can't have everything.  (As the sage says, "Where would you put it?"  :-/ )

In this case, what you really can't have is entirely encapsulated data that prototype functions have access to.  As elclanrs says, you're second example is fine if you're willing to forgo the privacy.  On the other hand, if the privacy is more important than memory, you can do this instead:

```
define(function(){
    function Numbox(){
        var counter = 0;
        this.add_and_show=function(){
            counter++; alert(counter);
        }
    }
    return Numbox;
}
```

Now `counter` is entirely private.  But each `Numbox` instance has its own private copy of `add_and_show`.  You can make your own decision about the tradeoff.  But I've never seen any technique which allows you to achieve both.

Comment: As you all suggested, I wouldn't mind about private variable anymore and what I did in example 2 seems to be what I want the most.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need this (tip, you probably don't), a way to do it is to keep track of instances and counters in the "private" scope, like so:

```
define(function(){

  var counters = [];
  var instances = [];

  function Numbox() {
    instances.push(this);
    counters.push(0);
  }

  Numbox.prototype = {
    addAndShow: function() {
      var idx = instances.indexOf(this);
      var counter = counters[idx]++;
      return counter;
    }
  };

  return Numbox;
});

var n = new Numbox();

console.log(n.addAndShow()); //=> 0
console.log(n.addAndShow()); //=> 1
console.log(n.addAndShow()); //=> 2

var n2 = new Numbox();

console.log(n2.addAndShow()); //=> 0
console.log(n2.addAndShow()); //=> 1

// More tests

console.log(n.addAndShow()); //=> 3
console.log(n2.addAndShow()); //=> 2
```

Comment: This works, but then becomes a memory leak if `Numbox` instances would usually fall out of scope and get garbage collected.  Because this closure keeps references to them, nothing will remove them at that time.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. That's why I don't think this is necessary. You can always manually remove the reference when you don't need it anymore I guess.

Comment: To clarify, you'd let the array with an undefined hole, and keep on going with new instances. Big arrays are typically not an issue.

Comment: Yes, but that would involve knowing when the element needs to be destroyed, and adding a `destruct` or some such mechanism, all the things we, ahem, love from C++.  :-).  Yes, this is a legitimate technique, and one I've used myself.  But I would only recommend it for long-lived objects, and I've generally found that I rarely have very many long-living objects, and in that case I can choose to do this more simply with the technique Quantas... and I suggested.